# How to prevent org-mode loading babel's major mode stuffs unless entering `org-src-mode`?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I have some `Java`'s scripts in a org file. And I use `meghanada-mode` in `java-mode`.

Each time I open this org file and do nothing, I get the following error since the `mehanada` server loaded by `java-mode` can't not find a project root for these scripts

```
Meghanada-Server Starting ...
error in process sentinel: meghanada--server-process-sentinel: Error:meghanada-server process stopped: finished
. Please check *meghanada-server-log* buffer
```

It seems that even I just open the org file org mode has already load all the major modes from org babels.

How can I prevent (or fix) this? I only want org load these things until I call <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>'</kbd>.

Comment: There are mutliple layers in the onion and you'll need to unravel them one by one. First, decouple the Org mode file question from the java question: restart your emacs, open a java file and see if you get the error. If you get an error, check the `*meghanada-server-log*` buffer and see what it says. Edit your question and add this information. If you don't get an error, then check the value of `org-babel-load-languages`: add that information to your question. Those are the first steps: let's see what you get and we'll go from there.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the function `org-babel-do-load-languages`. I think you'll want something like this:

```el
(org-babel-do-load-languages
 'org-babel-load-languages
 '((python . t)
   (C . t)
   (calc . t)
   (latex . t)
   (java . t)
   (ruby . t)
   (lisp . t)
   (scheme . t)
   (shell . t)
   (sqlite . t)
   (js . t)))
```

Just change the 't' to 'nil' for those you don't want.

Comment: I don't have `(java . t)` in it, but it still loads.

Comment: Do you have `(java . nil)` ?

Comment: No, I don't....